# Primefaces 5: selectOneMenu isn't making listener calls after being updated

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Code worked in a older version of Primefaces, but is failing in Primefaces 5.0. It's supposed to let a user pick an item in the first selectOneMenu (Group), which populates the second selectOneMenu (that part works). When the user selects an item from the second selectOneMenu, it's supposed to pull the matching code and update the Code, which isn't working. I can see that the listener in the Sub Group selectOneMenu isn't being called.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<h:outputLabel for="group" value="Group: *" />
<p:selectOneMenu id="group" label="Group" value="#{codeViewController.model.group}" style="width:100%">
    <f:selectItems value="#{Session.groups}" />
    <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{codeViewController.fetchSubGroup}" update="subGroup"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
<p:message for="group" />
    
<h:outputLabel for="subGroup" value="Sub Group: *" />
<p:selectOneMenu id="subGroup" label="Sub Group" value="#{codeViewController.model.subGroup}" style="width:100%">
    <f:selectItems value="#{codeViewController.model.subGroups}" />
    <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{codeViewController.fetchCode}" update="code"/>                                              
</p:selectOneMenu>
<p:message for="subGroup" />
    
<h:outputLabel for="code" value="Code: *" />
<p:inputText id="code" value="#{codeViewController.model.group.id.code}" label="Code">
    <f:validateLength minimum="5" />
</p:inputText>
<p:message for="code" />
```

Comment: Have you tried adding process="@this" in your ajax, or using f:ajax ?

Comment: I have tried adding process="@this" and it does not correct the issue. Using f:ajax just stops any updates from happening.